# Difference in importing a project in eclipse against cloning it through git and then opening it in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, github, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a git maven project.
We are a team of 6 developers.
I use git bash and tortoise git inorder to clone the project branch, whereas the rest of my team directly uses the git plugin in eclipse and import it from the git URL.
I came across a difference in these both processes that the project name in my eclipse was different than what happened to be with the rest of my teams'.
Am i missing something here?
Am i following a bad practise?
Why is there a difference in the project names when both my team and me are importing the same project?

Comment: Do the shared Git repositories contain the `.project` files (in which Eclipse stores the project name)?

Comment: Well I don't know that right now.. I will go check that tomorrow and report back. I think this has to do something with the project names being different. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I following a bad practice?

No, you're not following a bad practice.  It is merely a matter of preference.  The project name in each developer's local environment makes no difference, as long as each developer can identify the active project.

> Why is there a difference in the project names when both my team and I are importing the same project?

It's hard to say given the context of the question.  Some things could have happened that made the project names different.

1. You cloned the repository in a directory with a different name than the remote repository.
2. You used the default values in the wizard when importing the project into Eclipse.  The default Eclipse workspace is not where you cloned it, but is local to the Eclipse installation.
3. The Eclipse Git plugin names the project something other than what the remote name is.

If you are concerned about this (which you shouldn't be), then the standard practice to follow is to have the cloned directory root to be the same name as the remote.

Comment: Thankyou very much @Mania36 for clearing my doubts. I think am quite confident now.